# Iterate through an array of characters in C

Tags: c, while-loop, iteration, null-character

Recently I saw this while loop condition in C in the example below but I have no idea what the while condition really means and how the compiler knows when it is done. Could someone explain it to me?

This is what I believe it means: while loop iterates through the char array until the ending of the array since there is nothing else then the while loop ends, or am I wrong? I tried to use the same while loop but in another language such as Go, however, the compiler threw an error saying that I cannot use a non-bool.

```
// C program to demonstrate 
// example of tolower() function. 

#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int j = 0; 
    char str[] = "GEEKSFORGEEKS\n"; 

    // Character to be converted to lowercase 
    char ch = 'G'; 

    // convert ch to lowercase using toLower() 
    char ch; 

    while (str[j]) { // <- this part, how is this a condition?
        ch = str[j]; 

        // convert ch to lowercase using toLower() 
        putchar(tolower(ch)); 

        j++; 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the while loop can be understood as "while this string has characters" and as known in C strings or an array of chars contain a '\0' => Null character, in the end, once the while loop achieves it, it will stop the iteration.

So yeap! you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of an array of chars as following:

[image]

So as you see in the picture an array of chars is already a pointer, and each of the characters has an address, as well that the address of a pointer is the address of the first element, so when you declared

```
char str[] = "GEEKSFORGEEKS\n";
```

it was allocated in the memory like below:

```
[G][E][E][K][S][F][O][R][G][E][E][K][S][\n][\0]
```

The program will crash because you have a redeclaration of **ch** variable, as well there is no need to initialize the `char ch = 'G';` since you're overriding it in the while loop and it will take str[j], and so you started iterating at **j = 0** which the 1st index in the array **[G]**, as you're incrementing the loop will go until the null character **[\0]** and stop because there's no iteration after the **NULL**, in other examples you might see the following condition in the loop: `while(str[j] != '\0')` which is similar to your condition but just more specific.

You can gain more performance by iterating through the pointer just like the following:

```
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{
    char *str = "GEEKSFORGEEKS\n";

    while (*str)
        putchar(tolower(*str++));

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, you got your answer. Still, I wanna add some more details or an explanatory answer here.

> In C, a conditional statement will have either the value 1 or 0. In the end, they all are evaluated to Boolean values **true** or **false** or **1** or **0**.

So first, try to understand or dry run that `while(str[j])`. Guess what will be the value of `str[j]` when j = 0. It'll be the first character **"G"**. Similarly in the next iteration, you'll get the next character until *NULL* character or *String Termination* character. Now, anything in between those parentheses in `while(str[j])` will be considered as a conditional statement and they all are evaluated to 1 or 0. Now here's the thing that anyhow if that conditional statement isn't being evaluated specifically to 0, then It'll be supposed to have the value of 1.
So, here `str[j] when j = 0` will be evaluated as `1`, then next character and so on. Now, when we find `\0` which is an `escape character` equivalent to `0`. So, at `\0` while loop will terminate as the condition will be false.

> Can, you tell me what will be the output of this program?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if(printf("Hello TraineeGuy\n"))
        printf("TRUE");
    else
        printf("FALSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why are you declaring ```ch``` variable two times in the program? Isn't it throwing any error about that? @TraineeGuy